# Can't use static type for new instance of a private framework class - why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-privateapi

I'm currently trying to learn how to use private frameworks, just to gain some deeper understanding of these kinds of things.

So, while experimenting with ToneLibrary.framework ([See classdump](https://github.com/limneos/classdump-dyld/tree/master/iphoneheaders/iOS7.0.3/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneLibrary.framework)), I noticed that I am able to work with existing instances, but am unable to instantiate a class object from a private framework like I normally would myself.

For example, from the framework mentioned above, I have imported and TLToneManager.h and TLITunesTone.h.

I can do:

```
NSArray *tones = [[TLToneManager sharedRingtoneManager] installedTones];

for (id object in tones) {

    TLITunesTone *tone = (TLITunesTone *)object;

    NSLog(@"Tone: %@", [tone name]);
    NSLog(@"Tone: %@", [tone filePath]);

}
```

But I can't do:

```
TLITunesTone *newTone = [[TLITunesTone alloc] init];
[newTone setName:@"TestTone"];
```

as it will result in "the symbol for TLITunesTone cannot be found for architecture arm7v".

If I add `Class TLITunesTone = NSClassFromString(@"TLITunesTone");` before that code, it will complain that newTone is an undeclared identifier. I tried forward declaring the class, with the same result.

This however will work:

```
Class TLITunesTone = NSClassFromString(@"TLITunesTone");
id newTone = [[TLITunesTone alloc] init];
[newTone setName:@"TestTone"];
```

And I can now continue use newTone normally.

So my question is: Why can't I use a static type for an instance of a class which is part of a private framework?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  As you describe it, you have two identical sequences, the only difference being that the second uses `id` vs `TLITunesTone*` to declare `newTone`.  That difference would only affect the compiler, not runtime.  You also show no evidence that you actually have imported an implementation for TLITunesTone.

Comment: OK, I see -- the first case is using TLITunesTone for both a class name and a variable name -- a good reason to observe the convention of lowerCase initial characters for variable names.  The second works because TLITunesTone is a Class variable that recognizes `alloc`.  Neither makes much sense.

Comment: You should be able to do this. Try looking at the architectures your various configurations are building for, and the architectures your framework supports.

Comment: I'm aware that it should be the same at runtime. What I'd like to know is why I'm not getting that far in one case. I am linking to ToneLibrary.framework statically (via build phases). And as for the evidence that the implementation has been imported - the first of my code snippets will print all info about currently installed ringtones as expected which, I suppose, wouldn't work if there was no implementation for TLITunesTone available...

Comment: @CRD: It actually is working - the project compiles fine for the first and last code example. So it is not a problem with unsupported architectures, as I am using the same build configuration in all cases. The question is rather why the compiler complains about missing symbols when actually they aren't missing

Comment: @Hot Licks: I see how deviating from naming conventions is confusing when posted here, sorry for that. I preferred it this way to be able to refer to the class object upper case from there on

Comment: But the Class object and the class name are *not* interchangeable.  You (presumably) have the class name imported as TLITunesTone, and when you create a variable by the same name you "hide" the class name, causing all sorts of errors.

Comment: @Toastor - My thought on architectures is you might be building for multiple architectures, one of which is getting an error because the framework isn't supported, but running on an architecture that is supported. The code which is failing looks like the only one to reference the `TLITunesTone` class object and that is the missing symbol... Just a thought, might be completely wrong!

Comment: Hot Licks: Ok, I missed that. Thanks! If I use another name for the class variable I can use TLITunesTone as static type without any problems.
@CRD: I've been building for armv7 only and just tried armv7s and arm64 solo as well, same result

Comment: @CRD, that's a good thought, *in general*, but the question states that the error is given for architecture `armv7`.  In the case of private APIs, sometimes they're not actually implemented for the **simulator**, but will be for the actual device.  So, in this case, since the error is for a device build, that's not it.

Comment: @Toastor, which versions of Xcode / compiler / iOS are you using?  This works for me.  I compiled all snippets of your code successfully, with no warnings or errors.

Comment: @Nate: Xcode 5.1 (5B130a) / LLVM 5.1 / iOS 7.1
Interesting... which version of the ToneLibrary framework have you been using?

Comment: I just tested this on Xcode 4.6 / Apple LLVM 4.2 / iOS 6.1.  I used the headers, though, from the github site you linked to.

Comment: Hmmm.  I just tried it with Xcode 5.1, Apple LLVM 5.1, iOS 7.1, and it still worked.  However, it was with an old project, and I did not yet take Xcode's advice to "update to recommended settings".  So, I'm sure I have some old project settings in there.  You added ToneLibrary.framework in your project / target settings (Build Phases) under "Link Binary with Libraries"?  You're not trying to dynamically open this framework, are you?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I did try to dynamically load it when I first started playing with it, but that was in another project. In this one, the framework is statically linked via build phases.

Comment: I'm stumped.  Like I said, all your code works for me :(